# Probability: Student takes three tests

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution

> Suppose a student can take a test at most thrice. Once a test concludes, the student has to either accept the score or reject it and take the next test (until he takes the second re-test or the *third & final* test). The university has a rule that he can take the third test only if he gets less than $40$ in the second one. Taking the second test has no such restriction. At what score in the first test should a student consider retaking to maximize the expected final score? Assume that the score always comes from $\text{Uniform}[0,100]$ each time.

The expected score is $50$ each time. The student will consider retaking if he gets $< 50$ in the second test, so if he gets $< 40$ in the second test, he will definitely re-take the test. There's a $60\%$ chance that he'll keep the (expected) score of $50$ and $40\%$ chance that he will re-take after the second test.

I don't know how to proceed from here. I am looking for a more verbal and less mathematical explanation.

Comment: What is the question? The problem statement says what a student can, but does say what a student want. For example, if a student get 70% in the first test, will he take the second?

Comment: @kludg That's for us to calculate. His objective is to maximize the expected score.

Comment: Are scores necessarily whole number values?

Comment: @paw88789 no, reals

Comment: (1) In your Comment you say **"His objective is to maximize the expected score."** , @tinkerer89 , hence I had edited the Post with this line **"The student wants to maximize the expected score."** : Strangely , you have reverted that Edit (2) More-over , there was no Intro to the Issue , hence I had tried to include a Partial Intro , which too has been reverted (3) You say **"I am looking for a more verbal and less mathematical explanation."** , yet you have Accepted the totally Mathematical Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, we know that $m\ge 50$, and the student should retake if their score is below 50 and they are allowed to.
We are trying to find the probability density function $p(y)$.
Let $y\in[0,100]$ be a score.

If $y\in [0, 40)$, then the only possible way to obtain a score of $y$ is first getting a score below $m$, and then getting a score below 40, and finally getting a score of $y$.
Then $p(y)=\frac{m}{100} \frac{40}{100} \frac{1}{100}$ in this case.

If $y\in [40, m)$, then there are two ways to obtain a score of $y$:

1. Get below $m$; Get $y$
2. Get below $m$; Get below $40$; Get $y$

Then $p(y)=\frac{m}{100}\frac{1}{100}+\frac{m}{100}\frac{40}{100}\frac{1}{100}$ in this case.

If $y\in [m, 100]$, then there are 3 ways to obtain a score of $y$:

1. Get $y$ on the first take
2. Get below $m$; Get $y$
3. Get below $m$; Get below $40$; Get $y$

Then $p(y)=\frac{1}{100}+\frac{m}{100}\frac{1}{100}+\frac{m}{100}\frac{40}{100} \frac{1}{100}$ in this case.

The expected score is then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{100} y p(y)\, dy = -\frac{1}{200}m^2 + \frac{31}{50}m + 50.
\end{align*}
$$
It is easy to compute that $m=62$ maximizes the expected score.